# Why are my dropdown options updating after my Ajax call in the source code but not in the UI?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, drop-down-menu, materialize

I have a few django dropdown buttons that I want are originally empty, but I have a script that is called to go fetch the drop down options. I see the options populate in the source code, but they don't actually appear in the UI when I click on the drop down. Am I writing my Ajax call incorrectly?

**`html:`**

```
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
              <!-- adding dropdown selector for cryptocurrency symbol (type) -->
              <div id="symbol_selection" class="input-field col s12">
                <select id="selected_symbol">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your CryptoCurrency</option>

                </select>
              </div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <!-- adding dropdown selector for cryptocurrency market (physical currency type) -->
              <div id="market_selection" class="input-field col s12">
                <select id="selected_market">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your Market</option>
                </select>
              </div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <!-- adding function test button -->
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="test_btn" onclick="test_fxn()">Run Test</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
```

**`My Ajax Call:`**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "dropdowns",
    data: {
      "gettem": "gettem"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var op_items = data.symbols;
      var markets = data.markets;

      for (var i = 0; i < op_items.length; i++) {
        console.log(op_items[i])
        option = "<option value=" + op_items[i] + ">" + op_items[i].toString() + "</option>";
        $("#symbol_selection select").append(option);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < markets.length; i++) {
        console.log(markets[i])
        option = "<option value=" + markets[i] + ">" + markets[i] + "</option>";
        $("#market_selection select").append(option);
      }

    },

  });
});
</script>
```

[image]

The blue areas represent the first dropdown and the red represent the second. The output from data (in the Ajax call) is printed in the console log and can be seen in the source code viewer on the top right matching the returned Ajax options.

[image]

Comment: please show your Django response to the Ajax call

Comment: @HenryM My Django Response? (Sorry, I'm new to Django Web App Dev). The only thing I'm aware of currently is the console log. In my original setup, the "symbol_selection" element was only followed by one option, but after my Ajax call (on the right side) all of my new options are seen.

Comment: I suspect Django hides the `<select>` and creates its own HTML elements that substitute for it. You may need to call a Django method to refresh it from the `<select>`. I'm not familiar with Django so I don't know what that would be.

Comment: Django is returning  `data` in the line `success: function(data) {`.  Please show the view which does this

Comment: @HenryM I have included a new screenshot. It's hard to see but the 1st dropdown on the left has been clicked and is showing none of the options listed in the console log and source code viewer.

Comment: Please simply show the Django/Python code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone else will run into this issue, but after searching for a while there I did find a solution. My dropdown is a materializes (dropdown) selector, but it requires a script to initialize. It's not very clear in their documentation, but you have to also include a "OnChange" method as well.

The syntax on the page doesn't quite match the latest version out, but after playing around I got it to work.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      //~Method below is needed to initialize the materialize selection dropdown
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('select').formSelect();
      });
      //~Method below is needed to add the update feature when dynamically adding options
      //~This must be triggered after the changes occur in the ajax call.
      $('SELECT').on('contentChanged', function() {
          $(this).formSelect();
      });
    </script>
```

One other little nuance to it (-_-), you have to trigger it as well. I assumed, even after finding it, that on change meant it was a listener for any change, but you have to actually include than in your Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
              method: 'GET',
              url: "django_url_to_your_script",
              data:{"test":"test"},
              success:function(data){
                var op_items = data.symbols;
                var markets = data.markets;


                for(var i = 0 ; i < op_items.length; i++){
                  option = "<option value="+ op_items[i]+">"+ op_items[i].toString() +"</option>";
                  $("#symbol_selection select").append(option);
                }
                for(var i = 0 ; i < markets.length; i++){
                  option = "<option value="+ markets[i] + ">"+ markets[i] +"</option>";
                  $("#market_selection select").append(option);
                }
                  //THIS IS THE KEY! AFTER ALL YOU ADDITIONS HAVE BEEN MADE
                  //FORCE THE ONCHANGE TRIGGER TO OCCUR.
                  $("#market_selection select").trigger('contentChanged');
                  $("#symbol_selection select").trigger('contentChanged');

              },

            });
```

Now I get my dropdown that were added:
[image]